# issue with adding decimal point in front of an int

Tags: php

So I am trying to add a decimal point in front of a whole in (10)  The issue is I'm trying to use `sprintf();` but it seems to not be working for me :(.

Code:

```
sprintf(".",($percentamount));
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong thanks!

I have already tried `"%.f"`

Comment: It's an integer.  `printf`ing it as a *floating point* is going to put the decimal in the right place, not the wrong place.  You need to either put the decimal in by hand, or you need to transform the number into the *correct* value as far as `printf` is concerned...

Comment: lazy option: `$percentamount='.'.$percentamount;`

Comment: Iinteger is numbers. Adding in a decimal, makes it a string

Comment: Dagon and Charles thanks so much, I totally forgot about those :)  @Dagon yours worked like a charm and it's, the lazy option!

Answer (score -1):

if i understand you correctly you will take $percentamount variable which have to contain 10 as its value and just put '.' in front of it to make string '0.1' out of it - is it right? If yes than you could take 10 as digit and place it within a string as follows:

```
sprintf('.%d', 10); // %d stands for digit and means digit should be your second parameter
```

if you want to have 10 as string input you could write it as follows:

```
sprintf('.%s', '10');
```

if it is not the solution you looking for please describe it better and i'll try to help